# raspberrypi gstreamer1.0 alsasrc0: Internal data flow error

Tags: linux, usb, webcam, gstreamer, alsa

I have one problem trying to stream rtmp from logitech c210 webcam with sound.

I'v installed gstreamer1.0-omx and other needed stuf, but when i tryin to get video (for simplification let' write it into flv file):

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! \
omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! \
h264parse ! queue ! flvmux name=mux alsasrc device=plughw:1 ! audioresample \
! audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=1 ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=32000 ! queue ! mux. mux. \! filesink location=1.flv
```

And i got an error like:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2812): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 69507879 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
libv4l2: warning v4l2 mmap buffers still mapped on close()
Freeing pipeline ...
```

There is with some more debug info ( -vvv option):

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: actual-buffer-time = 200000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: actual-latency-time = 10000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioResample:audioresample0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter2.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVoAacEnc:voaacenc0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVoAacEnc:voaacenc0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVoAacEnc:voaacenc0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)48000, stream-format=(string)raw, level=(string)2, base-profile=(string)lc, profile=(string)lc, codec_data=(buffer)1188
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc:omxh264enc-omxh264enc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2812): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 561957256 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
libv4l2: warning v4l2 mmap buffers still mapped on close()
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I sepose there is a problem with alsa speed or buffer or such, so is there any solution how make it work?

I can record just sound by arecord or gstreamer also without any problem. Or just video also. The problem appears only by capturing video and sound together.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your alsasrc1.0 either hasn't been installed properly or not installed at all.i would try the following:

first try to additionally install alsasrc for gstreamer1.0:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-alsa
```

Sometime Linux just acts weird and although you have already installed a package the merging does not get done properly.

If the above solution didn't work try to install all the needed packages for your pipeline for gstreamer0.10 version and try your pipeline with `gst-launch-0.10`